# Update Clojure atom property

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic way to conj a new value into a vector which resides in a map, in an atom?

The closest I've been able to come is the following:

```
(def blog (atom {:posts []}))

(swap! 
    blog 
    (fn [current] 
        {:posts (conj (:posts current) {:title "War of Worlds"})}))
```

Which results in:

```
{:posts [:title "War of Worlds"]}
```

The use of a lambda feels unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: `update-in` is your friend.

Comment: (swap! blog #(update-in % [:posts] conj {:title "War of the Worlds"}))

Comment: ...that said, your original code _does not_ in fact prevent `:posts` from remaining a vector. You can easily test that `(conj [] :foo)` returns `[:foo]`, just as `(conj (list) :foo)` returns `'(:foo)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Where is the list coming from, though? If I'm dereferencing the value of :posts and passing that to conj, I'd think conj would know to create and return a new vector.

Comment: @pdoherty926, I cannot reproduce the list you claim to get -- I run the code you provide here, and `:posts` remains a vector. I suggest double-checking that there's nothing else going on in your environment.

Comment: See code and output from running it at http://ideone.com/zXCkHG -- no list anywhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're totally right. I must have mistakenly defined posts as a list when experimenting in the repl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do:

```
(swap! blog update-in [:posts] conj {:title "War of the Worlds"})
```

Both swap! and update-in follow the "update model" form and they can be profitably chained together like this. This is a very common pattern, particularly with a stateful container and nested map update.

"Update model" meaning functions of the form: `(defn u [context f & args])` invoked as `(apply f context args)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was envisioning. Thanks!